# cakephp authorization array parameters

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having trouble following the [cakephp blog authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) tutorial. The following code is shown, but since it's not well commented I'm not sure exactly what the params are referncing.

I have an items controller with an iteminfo action that I want only the creator of a particular item to be able to view. It is accessed by the following url where the number is the itemnumber and the iteminfo is the action

```
/items/iteminfo/3
```

For example

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Post->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

I tried modifying it to just this

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('iteminfo'))) { 
        print_r($this->request->params); //attempting to view the params array
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

I just wanted to view the params array so i know what to modify in my iteminfo action. Is there any way I can view this? Basically I want to see what the components of the array are so I know what to reference.

Here is the table for the items.

```
itemid    userid   itemname   itemcost  datecreated
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing:

```
if (in_array($this->action, array('iteminfo'))) { 
    debug($this->request->params);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess part of the confusion also lies in how the isAuthorized is called. Is it part of cakePHP in the sense that if that function is declared, it will always be checked, or do I have to call it from my iteminfo controller?

Comment: @user2268281 yes isAuthorized is part of AppController, its a part of Cake's Auth Component, you can check in cakephp doc's auth component for details..